# How to create a nested collection when creating a user in Firebase / Firestore where users can save bookmarked items

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to have a nested collection in firebase/firestore where I can save an authenticated users favorites. I was trying to create the collection when the user is created so I can just read/write to it later but I can't figure out how to create the collection. I have something like this:

```
//This function creates a new user. If the user already exists, no new document will be created
export const createUserDocumentFromAuth = async (
  userAuth,
  additionalInfo = {}
) => {
  if (!userAuth) return;

  const userDocRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.uid); //database instance, collection, identifier
  const bookmarkRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.id, 'bookmarks'); //This triggers error
  const userSnapshot = await getDoc(userDocRef);
  if (!userSnapshot.exists()) {
    //If user snapshot doesn't exist - create userDocRef
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();

    try {
      await setDoc(userDocRef, {
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...additionalInfo,
      });
      setDoc(bookmarkRef, { //Try to create a bookmarks collection here
        favorites: []
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error creating user', error.message);
    }
  }
  //if user data exists
  return userDocRef;
};
```

I can create the user just fine but not another collection at the same time. I also tried just creating the collection when a signed-in user clicks on the bookmark button like this but I get a type error in both cases `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n is undefined` every time.

```
export const addBookmarkForUser = async (userAuth, showId) => {
  const bookmarkRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.id, 'bookmarks');
  try {
    await setDoc(bookmarkRef, {
      favorites: showId
    });
  }catch(error){
    console.log('error creating bookmark', error.message)
  } 
};
```

I'm pretty new to Firebase / Firestore and all I want is to be able to save an item id in an array for an individual user when they click a button. If saving in an array is not ideal or there is any better way to do this, I am open to any suggestions at this point.

Answer (score 1):

> I was trying to create the collection when the user is created so I
> can just read/write to it later but I can't figure out how to create
> the collection.

A (sub)collection is only created **when you create the first document in it**. There is no way to *materialize* an empty collection without a document.

And it is normal that you get an error when using the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#doc) method as follows

```
const bookmarkRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.id, 'bookmarks');
```

because this method is used to create a `DocumentReference` and therefore you need to pass a path with an even number of path segments. In you case you pass 3 segments.

You could very well define the `CollectionReference` for the `bookmarks` subcollection as follows, using the [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#collection) method and passing the 3 segments

```
const bookmarkRef = collection(db, 'users', userAuth.id, 'bookmarks');
```

but, until you add a document in it, it will not exist in the database.

---

**Conclusion:** You will automatically create the user's `bookmarks` subcollection the first time you create a bookmark for the user.

For example:

```
const bookmarksCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users', userAuth.id, 'bookmarks');
await bookmarksCollectionRef.add({ ... })
```

Comment: Hello @Peshwari_Naan, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed to know. I apologize for my slow response as I am traveling at the moment and I have not had a chance to apply the solution. This explains why I was not able to create an empty collection though and it makes sense. I'll have time in the next couple days and I'll verify the solution here. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Alright - so I finally got this to work but the syntax was a little different and the `add` keyword didn't work for me. I used addDoc instead and for some reason it didn't like the collection ref. So
 
`export const addBookmarkForUser = async (userAuth, showId) => {
  try {
    await addDoc(collection(db, 'users', userAuth.uid, 'bookmarks'), {
      showId: showId,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error creating bookmark', error.message);
  }
};`
did the trick.